# Sort whole collection then save in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have a collection called "Forum".

I want to sort it by "forum_order" in ascending order then update whole collection sorted by "forum_order".

I tried following:

```
Forum.findByIdAndUpdate({}).sort({forum_order: 1}).exec(function(err, updatedTasks) { if (err) { console.log(err); } });
```

But didn't work.

[image]

If it was successful, "1st Forum" in the image should be above "3rd Forum" so that 1st Forum become 1st object in this 'forums' collection.

How can I fix this? I am new to mongodb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really something that makes sense in mongo: there's no way of updating the default order that the documents get returned to you. When you don't specify a sort, they'll return in an order that's easy for mongo.

Instead, you should specify the sort order when you `find` the documents: `db.forums.find({}).sort({forum_order: 1});`. If you have a large collection of fora, you may wish to add an index on `forum_order`.

Comment: I thought I had to sort then update original collection. Otherwise it will just need to sort every time I query something to DB which may result in performance issue. Anyway, then it doesn't look like I need to sort and update keys in a collection in mongo but rather, everytime I query, I just need to run sort then . Thank you very much!